# Mysql to return greatest to least results

Tags: mysql, sql

Not a sql guru but I have this query that counts the number of customers per dealership.

```
SELECT d_id, COUNT(DISTINCT c_number)
from distinct_customers
group by d_id
limit 5;
```

However, it is only returning the top results.

I am trying to create a query that returns the results from greatest to least limit to the to 5.

Comment: have you considered `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `ORDER BY` clause :

```
SELECT d_id, COUNT(DISTINCT c_number) AS NO
FROM distinct_customers 
GROUP BY d_id 
ORDER BY NO DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: this is the answer we're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one as well.

```
   SELECT d_id
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT c_number) AS NO
    FROM distinct_customers
    GROUP BY d_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT c_number) DESC LIMIT 5;
```